# RStudio crash (Lubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: rstudio

When I lunch RStudio I get:

```
rstudio
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x1260460, glyph=2797
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x1260460, glyph=2797
```

Then everytime I try to enter "Tools > Global Options..." menu RStudio crashes (cpu 100% for rstudio pid). How can the problem be solved?